# Facebook Marketing API | node js | "message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Facebook Marketing API to create a new ad campaign in Node.js.

I have successfully gotten an access token from this url:

```
var fbApi = {
'method': 'GET',
'url' : 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials'
}
```

I then make this POST request (using the 'request' module).
I am posting values for 'name' and 'campaign_group_status' which I understand are required values.

I am posting to the endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcampaign_groups
```

and I'm passing the access token via the URL as per this from the docs:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret
```

.

Full code  (sensitive info replaced by dummy data):

```
var request = require('request');

var fbOptions = {
    'name' : 'test2',
    'campaign_group_status' : 'PAUSED'
}

var fbOptionsString = JSON.stringify(fbOptions);



var fbPost = {
    'uri' : ' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_5374356645419299/adcampaign_groups?access_token=56345345453773242|iert_arfwYfwfwxD-pLxHcpASFTNm',
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    'body' : fbOptionsString
}

request(fbPost, function(error, response, body){
    console.log('request says ----', body);
})
```

.

Error response that I'm seeing:

```
request2 says ---- {"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}
```

.

Before I was getting an error about permission, and another saying the 'name' value was required.  Those have been solved. So I believe I have the right access and Facebook is getting the body content of the request.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: im not familiar with the API but it sure sounds like you made a bad request... do other API endpoints work?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcampaign/v2.3#examples) examples, they use the -F option in curl.

```
     -F, --form <name=content>
          (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type  multipart/form-data  according  to  RFC  2388.  This
          enables  uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <.
          The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
```

So you have to send the data from a post multi-part.
See [here](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) to learn how to do so with node-request.

```
var request = require('request');

var fbOptions = {
    'name' : 'test2',
    'campaign_group_status' : 'PAUSED'
}

// var fbOptionsString = JSON.stringify(fbOptions);
var fbPost = {
    'uri' : ' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_5374356645419299/adcampaign_groups?access_token=56345345453773242|iert_arfwYfwfwxD-pLxHcpASFTNm',
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    'formData' : fbOptions
}

request(fbPost, function(error, response, body){
    console.log('request says ----', body);
})
```

This code sample is not tested.